# How can I justify text in Inkscape?

Tags: inkscape, text

I have copied some text from Wikipedia, went to Inkscape, and pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>. So, the workspace looks like the following:

[image]

Now, I want to take the text inside the workspace and then want to justify the text.

If I break the lines, make the text box smaller, select the entire text, and then press Justify, I see that the Justify menu item is disabled.

How can I do what I want?

Comment: With the Text tool, click and drag a text box the size you want. Paste the text into the text box. This is really basic stuff. I suggest you look at some beginner tutorials. There are lots on youtube.

Comment: @BillyKerr, *click and drag a text box the size you want. Paste the text into the text box.* --- this doesn't work in this way.

Comment: Of course it works. [see example](https://imgur.com/x1zDup1)

Comment: I had the same problem. Inkscape doesn't seem able to flow text dynamically, only when first entering it.

Answer (score 0):

Using the text tool click and drag, same as drawing a rectangle

Answer (score 0):

You have to

1. Select your text box
2. select the text tool from the toolbox. This will activate the text editing menubar on top. There you can select the different justifications.

If you want to change text after the fact via the "property editor" on the right side, you have to press "apply" to activate the changes.